# "Android Device Monitor" "Dump View Hierarchy" shows a black rectangle

Tags: android, android-studio

I open Android Studio. Then I go Tools -> Android -> Android Device Monitor. I plug my phone into my computer, select it on the left, and hit the "Dump View Hierarchy" button. I should see a pretty copy of what's on my phone, but instead, I just see a big ol' dumb black rectangle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Weirdly, when you run Android Device Monitor from Android Studio for the first time, instead of just using the same Android SDK as Android Studio, it makes you enter a path to an Android SDK. I had this problem because I gave it the wrong SDK and as far as I can figure out, you can't change it.

The solution is not to run Android Device Monitor from Android studio, which is forever trapped trying to open the monitor for the wrong SDK. Rather, just run Android Device Monitor from the command line.

```
$ <path to the correct SDK>/tools/monitor
```